# How to make a branch from someone else's merge request on git/gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a userA who created a branch and pushed several commits to it on gerrit. Now me as userB want to pull all his branch and create a new one of my own as myself author and test few things. How can I do this? I want to pull his branch, then push a new branch with commit 1 to gerrit server such that all his changed files shows in my branch commit 1.

Example:

```
git fetch ssh://${userB}@gittest.me.com:12013/orange refs/changes/93/18696/26 && git checkout -b change-18696 FETCH_HEAD
```

What do I after above command to make my own branch out of it and test?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your aim here correctly,

1. `git fetch` (fetch the current state of all branches)
2. `git checkout change-18696` (switch to that branch's HEAD commit)
3. `git checkout -b your-new-branch` (create a new branch, with specified name, from your current position and then switch to it)

If you'd like to work from a specific commit on `change-18696`, instead of HEAD, then you'll need to put the commit hash in step 2 instead of `change-18696` - but otherwise it's the same basic process.